# Maven jar-with-dependencies doesn't include Log4j

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I use the maven-assembly-plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies.  When I execute the .jar file it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.dg.fs.test.integration.main.FSIntegrationTestMain.<clinit>(FSIntegrationTestMain.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

This is a submodule, but I don't know why that would matter.

I've built lots of jar-with-dependencies with this plugin in the past.  Now it is missing the transitive dependencies.  What's the problem?

Thanks.

Here's the pom.xml.

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>fs-integration-test</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.dg</groupId>
        <artifactId>fs-parent</artifactId>
        <version>4.42-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dg</groupId>
            <artifactId>fs-jaxb-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.55.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.arcitecta.mf</groupId>
            <artifactId>mfclient</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!--    <version>4.0.065</version>  -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.digital.globe.dmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>mediaflux-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
               <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <mainClass>com.dg.fs.test.integration.main.FSIntegrationTestMain</mainClass>
                       </manifest>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>        

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the scope for the log4j dependency? If it is `test` or `provided`, the assembly plugin may not pick it up.

Comment: log4j is obviously a managed dependency in the parent. What is the scope of log4j in the parent pom? If you do not know, run `mvn dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nailed it, SiKing.  In the parent pom.xml it was `<scope>provided</scope>`.  I changed it to `<scope>compile</scope>` in the project pom.xml and it is working correctly.